# Null pointer exception at createBitmap in android

Tags: android

I am working on android application. I used facebook like slideout navigation in my page. I am getting bitmap error in my class. I searched in google but i couldn't solve this. 
Please can anybody look into this issue. 
Thank you

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2700)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3127)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:12025)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2695)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:455)
at com.korovyansk.android.slideout.SlideoutHelper.prepare(SlideoutHelper.java:34)
at com.korovyansk.android.slideout.SlideoutActivity.prepare(SlideoutActivity.java:11)
at com.mccee.studytopic.Mypage.user(Mypage.java:58)
... 14 more
```

My code is:

```
public class Mypage extends FragmentActivity {
    public void user(View v) {
        int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources()
                        .getDisplayMetrics());
        SlideoutActivity.prepare(Mypage.this, R.id.main, width);
        startActivity(new Intent(Mypage.this, MenuActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
```

}
}

SlideoutActivity.class

```
public class SlideoutActivity extends Activity {

    public static void prepare(Activity activity, int id, int width){
        SlideoutHelper.prepare(activity, id, width);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mSlideoutHelper.activate();
        mSlideoutHelper.open();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            mSlideoutHelper.close();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private SlideoutHelper mSlideoutHelper;
}
```

SlideoutHelper.class

```
public class SlideoutHelper {

    private static Bitmap sCoverBitmap = null;
    private static int sWidth = -1;

    public static void prepare(Activity activity, int id, int width) {
        if (sCoverBitmap != null) {
            sCoverBitmap.recycle();
        }
        Rect rectgle = new Rect();
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
        int statusBarHeight = rectgle.top;

        ViewGroup v1 = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(id).getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
34
        Bitmap source = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        if (statusBarHeight != 0) {
            sCoverBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, statusBarHeight,
                    source.getWidth(), source.getHeight() - statusBarHeight);
            source.recycle();
        } else {
            sCoverBitmap = source;
        }
        sWidth = width;
    }

    public SlideoutHelper(Activity activity) {
        this(activity, false);
    }

    public SlideoutHelper(Activity activity, boolean reverse) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mReverse = reverse;
    }

    public void activate() {
        mActivity.setContentView(R.layout.slideout);
        mCover = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.slidedout_cover);
        mCover.setImageBitmap(sCoverBitmap);
        mCover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                close();
            }
        });
        int x = (int) (sWidth * 1.2f);
        if (mReverse) {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            final android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, x, 0);
            mActivity.findViewById(R.id.slideout_placeholder).setLayoutParams(
                    lp);
        } else {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            final android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 0);
            mActivity.findViewById(R.id.slideout_placeholder).setLayoutParams(
                    lp);
        }
        initAnimations();
    }

    public void open() {
        mCover.startAnimation(mStartAnimation);
    }

    public void close() {
        mCover.startAnimation(mStopAnimation);
    }

    protected void initAnimations() {
        int displayWidth = ((WindowManager) mActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay()
                .getWidth();
        final int shift = (mReverse ? -1 : 1) * (sWidth - displayWidth);
        mStartAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE,
                0, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, shift,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0);

        mStopAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, -shift,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0);
        mStartAnimation.setDuration(DURATION_MS);
        mStartAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        mStartAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mCover.setAnimation(null);
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                final android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        shift, 0);
                mCover.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        });

        mStopAnimation.setDuration(DURATION_MS);
        mStopAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        mStopAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mActivity.finish();
                mActivity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    private static final int DURATION_MS = 400;
    private ImageView mCover;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private boolean mReverse = false;
    private Animation mStartAnimation;
    private Animation mStopAnimation;
}
```

Comment: **SlideoutHelper** is a inner class or outer class?

Comment: hi no facebook like slideout navigation is a library which I used..in that slideoutactivity class and slideouthelper class are there

Comment: SlideoutActivity.prepare(Mypage.this, R.id.main, width); - looks to me as if that id should be a drawable. im not sure since i dont know the libs documentation.

Comment: When do you call `public void user(View v)`? It seems to me that the Context is still null.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 ViewGroup v1 = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(id).getRootView();
 v1.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
v1.layout(0, 0, v1.getMeasuredWidth(), v1.getMeasuredHeight()); 

v1.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap source = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```